# Why do full-screen mobile game ads switch the position of the close button?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, games, advertisement, close

Many mobile games have full-screen pop-up ads. These ads have 2 parts: a video, and an app screen with a download button. The first close button could be on the top-left or top-right, but after you press it the second screen will have the close button on the opposite side. Why do they do that? I've seen this on both iOS and Android. Are the advertisers trying to "trick" users into clicking on the ads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are the advertisers trying to "trick" users into clicking on the ads?

Likely this.